# How to calculate the threefold convolution $f*f*f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, convolution

Somehow this convolution is driving me crazy. I am trying to calculate for the [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) $f:=1_{[0,1]}$ the threefold convolution $$f*f*f$$

But honestly, it does not work somehow.

$$f*f(s)=\int_0^1 1_{[0,1]}(s-t) dt$$ which I thought to be $0$ for $s\le 0$, $s$ on $(0,1)$ and $2-s$ on $[1,2]$ and $0$ if $s>2$. So, then I would need to calculate $f*f*f(s)=\int_0^1 (f*f)(s-t) dt$, but I do not trust my calculation anymore. Does anybody here know how to do this easily or has an idea about what the result will be?

Comment: Your $f\ast f$ looks good. It might be easier to compute the threefold convolution as $\int_{s-1}^{s} (f\ast f)(t)\,dt$. You will get a piecewise quadratic function that fits together to give a $C^1$ function globally, its support will of course be $[0,3]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing that I find useful in these kinds of problems is to remember that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int f(x-t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int f'(x-t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int(\delta(x-t)-\delta(x-1-t))g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=g(x)-g(x-1)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\text{if }x\in[0,1]\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}
$$
$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

Using $(1)$, we get $g'(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$

$$
g(x)=\int_0^1f(x-t)f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
=\left\{\begin{array}{}
x&\text{if }x\in[0,1]\\
2-x&\text{if }x\in[1,2]\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}
$$
$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

Using $(1)$, we get $h'(x)=g(x)-g(x-1)$
$$
h(x)
=\int_0^1f(x-t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\frac12x^2&\text{if }x\in[0,1]\\
3x-x^2-\frac32&\text{if }x\in[1,2]\\
\frac12x^2-3x+\frac92&\text{if }x\in[2,3]\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.\tag{4}
$$
$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]