# Calculating the convolution of piecewise constant functions

Tags: calculus, convolution

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ on $[-1,1]$. Find $f*f*f$

$(f*g)(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(x-t)\,dt$.

So $(f*f)(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{4}x+\frac{1}{2} & -2\le x \le 0 \\ \frac{-1}{4}x+\frac{1}{2} & 0 < x \le 2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

This is almost identical to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631302/how-to-calculate-the-threefold-convolution-fff)

Which this answer in this questions does now clearly explain how to find the limits of integration. I figured it out for $f*f$, but I am now lost in trying to calculate $f*f*f$.

I know that $(f*f*f)(x)$ will be in three pieces on $[-3,-1],[-1,1],$ and $[1,3]$, but I do not know how to set up my integrals.

Comment: Should the domain for $f(x)$ be $[-1,1]$? Because if it's really $[-2,2]$ the domain of $f*f(x)$ should be $[-4,4]$.

Comment: Yes thank you, edit made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convolution is $f*f*f(w)=\int_{x}\int_{y} f(x)f(y)f(w-x-y) dydx$. We seek the integration limits, firstly for $x$ given $w$ (with $-3\lt w\lt 3$), then for $y$ given $w,x$.

**Limits for $x$ given $w$:**

- $-1\lt x\lt 1$
- $w-2\lt x\lt w+2\qquad \text{(lower bound comes from $x=w-y-z\;$ with $y=z=1$)}$
  $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(upper bound comes from $x=w-y-z\;$ with $y=z=-1$)}$

So the limits for $x$: $\qquad\max\{-1,w-2\}\lt x\lt\min\{1,w+2\}$

Note:

- $-1\lt w-2$ iff $w\gt 1$
- $1\lt w+2$ iff $w\gt -1$

Hence, we split the interval $w\in [-3,3]$ at points $-1,1$.

$\\$

**Limits for $y$ given $w,x$:**

- $-1\lt y\lt 1$
- $w-x-1\lt y\lt w-x+1\qquad \text{(lower bound comes from $y=w-x-z\;$ with $z=1$)}$
  $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(upper bound comes from $y=w-x-z\;$ with $z=-1$)}$

So the limits for $y$: $\qquad\max\{-1,w-x-1\}\lt y\lt\min\{1,w-x+1\}$

$\\$

**For interval $w\in(-3,-1)$:**

- $-1\lt x\lt w+2$

$\\$

- $\max\{-1,w-x-1\} = -1$
- $\min\{1,w-x+1\} = w-x+1$

$\qquad\therefore\quad -1\lt y\lt w-x+1$

$\\$

**For interval $w\in(-1,1)$:**

- $-1\lt x\lt 1$

$\\$

- $\max\{-1,w-x-1\} = -1 \text{ only when $x\gt w$}$
- $\min\{1,w-x+1\} = 1 \text{ only when $x\lt w$}$

So if $-1\lt x\lt w$ then $w-x-1\lt y\lt 1$.

And if $w\lt x\lt 1$ then $-1\lt y\lt w-x+1$.

$\\$

**For interval $w\in(1,3)$:**

- $w-2\lt x\lt 1$

$\\$

- $\max\{-1,w-x-1\} = w-x-1$
- $\min\{1,w-x+1\} = 1$

$\qquad\therefore\quad w-x-1\lt y\lt 1$

$\\$

So our integrals are:

For $-3\lt w\lt -1$:

\begin{align}
f*f*f(w) &= \int_{x=-1}^{w+2}\int_{y=-1}^{w-x+1} f(x)f(y)f(w-x-y)\;dydx \\
&= \left(\dfrac{w+3}{4} \right)^2
\end{align}

For $-1\lt w\lt 1$:

\begin{align}
f*f*f(w) &= \int_{x=-1}^{w}\int_{y=w-x-1}^{1} f(x)f(y)f(w-x-y)\;dydx \\
&\qquad + \int_{x=w}^{1}\int_{y=-1}^{w-x+1} f(x)f(y)f(w-x-y)\;dydx \\
&= \dfrac{3-w^2}{8}
\end{align}

For $1\lt w\lt 3$:

\begin{align}
f*f*f(w) &= \int_{x=w-2}^{1}\int_{y=w-x-1}^{1} f(x)f(y)f(w-x-y)\;dydx \\
&= \left(\dfrac{w-3}{4} \right)^2
\end{align}

It might help to see the limits of integration by looking at how the plane $x+y+z=w$ moves through the cube $[-1,1]^3$ as $w$ varies from $-3$ to $3$.